# Any idea to improve speed of Cholesky decomposition of block-band-sparse matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods

I am working with sparse matrices in R. I need their Cholesky decomposition.

The structure of the matrices is what you could call "band-block-sparse" that is the matrix is made of blocks with a band matrix structure with depth 3 or 4, and the block themselves are sparse.

A picture is better than a thousand words. My matrix looks like that:

```
B1  B2t  B3t     0      0        0      0     0  
B2  B1´  B2t    B3t     0        0      0     0  
B3  B2   B1´´   B2t    B3t       0      0     0  ... and so on  
0   B3    B2   B1´´´   B2t      B3t     0     0  
0   0     B3    B2    B1´´´´    B2t    B3t    0  
0   0     0     B3      B2    B1´´´´´  B2t  B3t  
... and so on ...
```

With B1, B2, B3 sparse and of moderate size (50 or 100).
The block-matrix has size in the order of hundreds.
The structure is not block-Toeplitz, B1 is allowed to vary but remains sparse.

I currently am using Matrix::chol in order to solve systems involving this matrix and it is all right - actually better than Matrix::Cholesky because of the block-band structure, I guess. However I have to do that lots of times, so every tenth of second matters. Does anyone have an idea to do this better ?

Comment: You can speed it up _if_ you know that the nonzero pattern of the block matrix does not change between iterations.  See, e.g., `help("update,CHMfactor-method")`. Otherwise, you might be out of luck.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I do have some regularities. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Hello again, unfortunately this did not give any improvement. The problem lies, I believe, in the block-band structure: the naive Matrix::chol() should be close to optimal, therefore Matrix::Cholesky brigs little improvement, with the overhead of permutation. Matrix::update does not better than Matrix::chol. Thank you for your time nonetheless !

Comment: I'll try to write and share an example (probably not today) where the speed-up with `update` is non-negligible, and you can compare ...

Comment: That would be really nice of you ^_ ^

Comment: Just wondering, could it be the case that the main Toeplitz structure is infinite?

Comment: Hello @kvantour, I thik that I see where you are going. Unfortunately, there is an error in my presentation: the diagonal blocks are allowed to change. Therefore, Toeplitz tricks won't work. Sorry about the error and thank you for your input !